# FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: wpf, filenotfoundexception, syncfusion

I have a `WPF` Class library that I am trying to reference at runtime form another project with the code below. All works fine until I try to add a 3rd party DLL which then raises the error below, the 3rd party DLL is present in the same folder as the WPF Class Library. Any ideas, please?

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Syncfusion.Tools.Wpf, Version=15.4460.0.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Code :

```
   Dim DLLAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Filename)

   For Each t As Type In DLLAssembly.GetExportedTypes
        Dim obj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
```

Comment: Which ide do you use? I think you shouldn't put the file into your classes folder.

Comment: I am using VS 2017, are you suggesting putting the 3rd party DLL in a classes folder under the plugin folder?

Comment: That did not work

Comment: No i didnt i say put to resources folder

Comment: No that did not work

Comment: Syncfusion assemblies are not free, so not everyone can use them. You'd better use the vendor forum, https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/

Comment: We have a global Syncfusion licence

Answer (score 0):

From your provided error details, we suspect that you have not referred the dependency assembly of Syncfusion.Tools.WPF. Can you refer "Syncfusion.Shared.WPF" assembly in your application and check the reported error?
Also ensure that you are referring the correct Framework assembly version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a different company's dll. The problem was I actively used (and referenced in my solution) two of their dlls, but those two referenced something like six others.

The fix was to manually copy those six other dll files into the bin directory my project was compiling to (next to the myproject.exe file). I'd prefer the company clean up their mess, but I couldn't afford to wait on them to get it together.

Answer (score 0):

From the exception message, it is clear that one of the dependency assembly of the `Syncfusion.Tools.Wpf` is missing in your project reference.

You can refer the [Syncfusion help website](https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/) for knowing about the [dependencies](https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/control-dependencies).

> **Link:** https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/control-dependencies.
>
> **Nuget org link:** https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Tools.WPF/

As mentioned in the @mythily [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51378254/5395773) you are missing the `Syncfusion.Shared.WPF` assembly reference in your project file.